# Error in shell script to get Android's source info from logcat

Tags: android, bash, shell, android-ndk

I am trying to use this shell script to get detailed error from ndk as mentioned here [[link]](https://groups.google.com/d/msg/android-ndk/YeoQxKvf08M/_Ew2IsV1If4J). But I am getting some errors, I don't know shell scripting, can anyone help me with this here?

**CODE**

```
if [ $# -lt 1 ]
then
    echo usage: $0 app
    exit 0
fi

APP=$1
LOG_FILE=$2

if [ ! -n "${ANDROID_NDK}" ]
then
    ANDROID_NDK=`dirname $0`
    echo ANDROID_NDK is not set using ${ANDROID_NDK}
fi

ADDR2LINE=${ANDROID_NDK}/toolchains/arm-linux-androideabi-4.4.3/prebuilt/windows/bin/arm-eabi-addr2line


if [ ! -s $LOG_FILE ]
then
    echo File $LOG_FILE does not exist or empty.
    exit 0
fi

while read LINE
do
    echo $LINE

    if [[ $LINE =~ ^.+\#[0-9]{2}\ +pc\ +([0-9A-Fa-f]{8})\ +(.+\.so).?$ ]] 
    then
            ADDR=${BASH_REMATCH[1]}
            SO=`basename ${BASH_REMATCH[2]}`
            SRC=`${ADDR2LINE} -C -f -e ${ANDROID_NDK}/out/apps/${APP}/armeabi/$
{SO} ${ADDR} 2>/dev/null`
            echo ${SRC}
```

**OUTPUT**

```
./stack.sh: line 42: conditional binary operator expected
./stack.sh: line 42: syntax error near `=~'
./stack.sh: line 42: `        if [[ $LINE =~ ^.+#[0-9]{2}\ +pc\ +([0-9A-Fa-f]{8})\ +(.+\.so).?$ ]] '
```

Answer (score 0):

The `=~` operator was added in version 3 of Bash; you might need to update.